# "NoSuchMethodError: Predef$.any2ArrowAssoc" when updating to Scala 2.10

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I am running my scala code from java and it was working fine before when I was using scala 2.9.1 now I upgraded from 2.9.1 to 2.10.4 and I have this issue

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.any2ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/Predef$ArrowAssoc
```

Can anyone tell me whats the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you have a dependency clash. That is, you may have updated your code to use Scala 2.10 but you can't updated your dependencies to use Scala 2.10. For those libraries which are Scala base (not Java based) do you have things imported as

```
"com.foo" %% "name" % "version.number"
```

and not just `name_2.9`?

Comment: I have a java web project in which I have dependencies to scala projects I run maven clean -> maven install on the scala projects and then updated my web project to have the updated code.. In dependencies I have the version numbers

Comment: @wearybands Make sure if you upgrade to 2.10 that you also change the dependency versions. Scala is not major or minor backwards compatible (Major.minor.patch)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by dependency versions? Dependency versions of the scala projects?

Comment: The byte code generated by the Scala compiler is not guaranteed to be the same between a library of version 2.9 and one of 2.10 even if the methods and code backing them are exactly the same.

Comment: So you mean I should change (for all the maven based scala projects which are included as dependency in my java project) the version number and then compile it with new scala and update my java project to the latest version of the code generated?